# How do I sort photos by date taken in Apple Photos?

Tags: photos.app

Is there a way to sort photos in an album in Apple Photos by date taken? The answer must be "yes", but I can't find it. The options that seem to refer to date (e.g., *Keep Sorted by Oldest*) seem to sort by the date the photo was added to the album.

Comment: Can you please clarify the version of macOS you're running and version of Photos app? The answers will differ otherwise (e.g. the answer provided by leon.stef is accurate in some cases, depending on versions and what you're accessing within the app).

Comment: @Monomeeth: Everything is current: macOS 10.12.2 (16C67); 2.0 (3130.0.240).

Answer (score -3):

On the menubar click:

View > Keep sorted by date

Comment: There's no such option. Just *View > Sort > Keep Sorted by Newest First*.

Comment: That's what it said on the official apple website.

Comment: Could you provide a link? What version are they referring to? An keep in mind: the question is about sorting *by date taken* (not date added) *in an album* (not in outside albums).